# calling the column_name in the table while connecting via Oracle DB

Tags: ruby, oracle, t-sql, activerecord, oci8

I am trying to get the value from the table(employee)connecting through
the oracle database. Since there are 100s of values in one column, I would need to iterate the table and get the exact value.

I have the code that works if I use the index no. such as row[1] but I
wanted to use the column_name "first name" instead of row[1]. Below is
the code that I have which works.
Code:

```
def load_borrower

connection = OCI8.new('usrname', 'pwd', //host:portno/sid') 

connection.exec(("SELECT BI_PREFIX, BI_FNAME, BI_MNAME, BI_LNAME, B.BI_SUFFIX, BI_ID_TYPE, BI_ID_NUMBER, BI_DOB,    B1.*, R.*, M.*, C.*, L.* FROM EMPLOYEE, SC_BORROWERPREF_NEW S1, BORROWER_NEW B, BORROWERPREF_NEW B1, RES_ADD R, MAIL_ADD M, CLOS_ADD C, LLORD_ADD L WHERE S2=SCENARIO_ID = S1.SCENARIO_ID AND S1.PREF_ID = B1.PREF_ID AND B1.BORROWER_ID = B.BORROWER_ID AND B1.PREF_ID = R.RES_PREF_ID AND B1.PREF_ID = M.MAIL_PREF_ID AND B1.PREF_ID = C.CLOS_PREF_ID AND B1.PREF_ID = L.LLORD_PREF_ID  AND S.RELEASE_ID= "1" AND S.SCENARIO_NO = '2' ORDER BY S1.SC_BORROWERPREF_ID") do |row|

$BI_PREFIX=row[0].to_s

$BI_FNAME=row[1].to_s

$BI_MNAME=row[2].to_s

$BI_LNAME=row[3].to_s

$BI_SUFFIX=row[4].to_s

$BI_BI_ID_TYPE=row[5].to_s

$BI_BI_ID_NUMBER=row[6].to_s

$BI_DOB=row[7].to_s

$BI_EMAIL=row[9].to_s

$BI_CELL_PH=row[11].to_s

$BI_WORK_PH=row[12].to_s

$BI_PREF_CONT=row[13].to_s

$BI_MAR_STATUS=row[16].to_s

$BI_EMP_STATUS=row[23].to_s

$BI_EDUC_YEARS=row[17].to_s

$BI_NUM_DEPEND=row[21].to_s

end

end
```

Now I'm running the above functions below

```
load_borrower
```

So the code above right now works fine. But As you can see from above, I am defining the variables from the db table as row[5], row[24] like that which is very hectic and time consuming although it works. So I was just wondering if we have any method or command to use the column_name such that it gets the value from the row and the column such as row['Emp_id'] instead of finding about the index of every column_name.

I am not sure if this is a drawback of Ruby as it treates the table from the db as an array and may be that's why we can't specify by column_name.

Comment: Try `row.EMP_ID` or `row.emp_id`?

Comment: I don't see any Watir methods being invoked in your code, so I'm confused as to why the question has a watir tag.

Comment: @zabba: row.EMP_ID doesn't work as it gives a method error.

Comment: Fundimentally this issue has nothing to do with Watir, it's about accessing an Oracle DB using RUBY.. Including the other code just makes for more to read and confuses the issue.  (frankly I think we would be better off if someone could revert the question back a few edits to where we just had the code that was trying to access the db)

Comment: Ok Chuck, i've removed other code than the one that's accessing oracle db. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly it appears you are a bit confused by the boundaries and separations between the various bits of technology you are using.  There is no Watir in the code you provided, NONE. it's all pure Ruby and a tiny bit of stuff from the OCI8 Gem. A GEM is a standard way that Ruby folks use to distribute code libraries and programs written in the Ruby language. See [HERE](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/book/1) for more info to better understand what a Gem is and how they are used.

Watir is another Ruby gem that is for driving web-browsers, and you might be using it elsewhere in your code, but it doesn't relate to this question or OCI8 other than both of them being Ruby code libraries distributed as Gems.  So lets leave it aside so as to not confuse things.

The behavior you are seeing is how the OCI8 gem works, NOT anything to do with Ruby specifically.  If you want something more elegant, then look into different gems that have been created for doing db access with Ruby, for example ActiveRecord, which was suggested in another answer already.  The OCI8 Gem only returns an array if you have the results feeding into a block like you do in your current code.  Otherwise the results are in an object called a Cursor, and you can use the cursor's fetch_hash method to get fetched data as a Hash. The hash keys are column names.  (see http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/api_OCI8Cursor.html)

Allow me to **strongly recommend** that you spend a little time learning a bit more about the Ruby language before you tear much further into your current project. Given the nature of the coding you seem to be doing, I'd advise you to read Brian Marik's book "Everyday Scripting with Ruby", thats going to give you a lot better understanding of the technology you are using, and you'll understand better when we toss around terms like 'hash' as I just did.

If you will allow a bit of general advice in terms of how you are going about interfacing with your database.  IMHO, you should be taking advantage of the db by constructing a query that returns JUST the data you want, instead of grabbing huge amounts of data and trying to parse through it manually.  It's better use of the resource, uses less memory, takes less time to transfer the info from the db, and no matter how good your parsing code might be, it won't be as good as what the Oracle people wrote.  Let the db do the heavy lifting, that's what it's there for.

If what you are dealing with here is data to drive your testing, or validate results, rather than construct one huge monolithic array, I'd recommend you use a much more modular approach.  Use one global variable such as the EMP_ID of the current user you are testing with or against, and have the test code get query results for just the values needed for each validation, or a small logical group of validations like the parts of an address.  It's a lot easier to build up stuff that way on a case by case basis working as you go, instead of trying to write the whole data retrieval bit in one giant piece that will be a nightmare to maintain.

As it stands all your test code that is verifying function or validating how the site works is going to be tightly coupled to a big monolithic piece that fetches the data from the db.  that creates a lot of dependencies and makes your test code hard to maintain.  If you deal with things in a more modular way, where each validation step retrieves just the data it needs, then it's a lot easier to expand or modify your test code as the site or database changes.

Comment: *sigh*  you've just made things more confusing by doing that.  Watir doesn't really have anything to do with your question.

Comment: True Chuck, but i'm using ruby for Watir so it's kinda related. Since you wanted the watir code, i put it in there. People who read the problem will probably understand what i really want to say.

Comment: Since i am using oci8 gem which is the one of the gem of watir, i thought i would get help from people that have used oci8 gem in watir and accessed db by column_names. Btw, i haven't started using Ruby or Watir at my project. We are currently using SAHI which is working fine. I was just trying to see how much watir is efficient with my current project. Thanks

Comment: I never asked you to post the Watir code, I merely pointed out there was no watir code in your question and in fact the question had nothing to do with watir.  What you are asking about is how to get data from oracle and be able to address things by column name.  what you want to do with it after that doesn't really matter

Answer (score 0):

If you had an array containing the column names then you could zip it up with the row array and build a hash:

```
Hash[column_names.zip( row )]
```

I would recommend using activerecord for this though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
connection = OCI8.new('usrname', 'pwd', //host:portno/sid') 

cursor = connection.exec(("SELECT BI_PREFIX ...")
cols = cursor.get_col_names

while r = cursor.fetch
  $BI_PREFIX=r[cols.index('BI_PREFIX')].to_s
  ...
end
```